# ReactJS fetch triggering page reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax

I am fairly new to ReactJS and done a couple of projects but I'm currently experiencing a problem on a new project which I've not seen before.

I have a button which fires an `onClick` event to post some data to an API as an AJAX request, but something is triggering the page to refresh and I don't know what it is.

Below is my button:

```
<input
  style={{ width: 70 + "%", marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: "auto" }}
  type="text"
  className="form-control"
  placeholder="someone@example.com"
  onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
/>
<button
  style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
  type="button"
  onClick={submitUserInterest}
  className="btn btn-primary"
  >
  Register Your Interest
</button>
```

and my `submitUserInterest` is s follows:

```js
const submitUserInterest = (event) => {
  console.log("Submit event");
  console.log(event);
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  const postArray: any = {
    email: email,
  };

  api.sendRequest(postArray).then(function (result: any) {
    if (result.result === 0) {
      //setShowConfirmModal(true);
    }
  });
};
```

The `sendRequest` method looks like the following:

```js
export const sendRequest = (postArray) => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let url = "";

    const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

    if (env === "production") {
      url = "/private/";
    } else {
      const host = window.location.host.substr(
        0,
        window.location.host.indexOf(":")
      );
      url = "http://" + host + "/private/";
    }

    const formData = new FormData();

    for (const name in postArray) {
      formData.append(name, postArray[name]);
    }

    fetch(url + "/service.php", {
      method: "post",
      body: formData,
      credentials: "include",
    }).then(function (response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        alert("Something went wrong. Status Code: " + response.status);
        reject(response);
        return;
      }

      response
        .json()
        .then(function (data) {
          resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.error("Caught Error: " + err);
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  });
};
```

If I remove the call to `api.sendRequest` then the page refresh doesn't happen, but something in the sendRequest method triggers the page refresh, but when the page refreshes I also see the following error in the console which I've not seen before:

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If
> you're seeing this, you're accessing the method `movementX` on a
> released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op function. If you
> must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().
> See *link redacted as SO won't accept short links* for more information.

Comment: I don't see anything inside `sendRequest` that would trigger the refresh. Is that all there is to it?

Comment: Yep sendRequest is the entire method, I've used this in other ReactJS project without problem so its really odd. I've spent the last couple of days trying to figure this issue but having no joy :(

Comment: So if you've used it before elsewhere and wasn't causing issues perhaps the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: this is problem I don't know where it would be, If I remove the sendRequest call the page doesn't refresh and I don't recall seeing the error about synthetic events reused so I'm at a bit of a loss. Its a really simple straight forward single component app with just this one single API call, so there's not a lot to go wrong

Comment: If you could replicate this in a `CodeSandbox` example that'd be helpful. I just don't see anything there that'd cause a refresh.

Comment: I've managed to figure out, its a very odd reason so I've added an answer

Comment: Is your `React` application served by `PHP`? Are you perhaps using a script that spins a development server and when there are changes to that directory it refreshes your application? Something like this - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#npm-start-or-yarn-start If `service.php` adds/deletes/updates files within that directory that'd cause a refresh if you're running your `React` application in development mode.

Comment: The react app uses the create-react-app and uses the node dev server. I think you are right about the changes being detected as the PHP script I was posting to was writing to a log file in the same directory as the PHP script so in react-project/public/private/log.txt so I assume when the log file was being updated, the dev server was triggering a reload as it detected a change. I thought it was only the items within the /src folder where the components are trigger the update, not what's in the public folder

Comment: It's most likely both `src` & `public` and that's definitely what's happening. If this is a production environment, you shouldn't be running it this way, so you will have to reconsider how your application is setup.

Comment: It wasn't production it just on my dev PC so rethought how it would access the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure it although I have no idea what triggers this.

The PHP script that I was posting I hosted within the reactjs project so it was `reactProject/public/private/service.php`

The private directory where the PHP being located is in the same directory where reactjs puts the index.html and favicon etc.

I set apache up so reactProject/public was the document root so the react project could just post to /private/service.php and its this that causes the reload.

I've put the PHP into a completely separate web directory outside of the react project and set apache to use this as the document root instead and changed the URL in the react project to point to this location and now it works as expected without page refresh.

I have no idea why posting to a php script within the directory of the react project would cause a page reload though